# Broken Pip on MSYS2

Tags: python, pip, mingw-w64, msys2

I have a problem where anytime I try to use Pip in the MSYS shell I get this error:
`AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'TCP_NODELAY'`

All I've done so far is:
`pacman -Syu`
`pacman -Su`
`pacman -S glib2-devel python3-pip git make nano pkg-config gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`

When I try to use `pip` to list or install, I get the error mentioned above. This is a brand new error, and I've followed the same procedure multiple times without this result. I would greatly appreciate some help!

**Update**: Someone on [GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-packages/issues/2050) is having the same issue, and it seems to be related to Python 3.8.5. After downgrading to Python 3.8.4 it seems to work, though I haven't tried it yet.

1. You can remove your old Python using `pacman -R python` (you need to remove dependencies first)
2. Then you can download Python 3.8.4 and Pip 20.0.2-1 from [here](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/)
3. Finall you can install using `pacman -U <package name>` (I installed from my home/user directory)
4. Reinstall dependencies using `pip3`.

[Source](https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/)

**Update**: I am also having trouble installing things with `pipx`, if anyone else is having the same issue?

Comment: Same pip issue here, you aren't alone

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer on Superuser.

Comment: Looks like the issue got fixed: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/pull/2054

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
sudo pacman -Su
sudo pacman -S glib2-devel python3-pip git make nano pkg-config gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3
```